# Python selecting columns with * plus another column

Tags: python, pandas

In Python I'd like to specify a list of columns with a wildcard and also additional columns. Example: suppose a dataframe `df` has columns `x1`, `x2`, `y`, `z` and I want `['x1', 'x2', 'y']`. I'd like to do this with a wildcard using something like:

`mask = df.columns.str.contains('x*')
 df.loc[:, [mask, 'y']].head()`

I am getting error: TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution should be changed for get columns by wildcard, convert to list and add `y`:

```
cols = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('x.*?')].tolist() + ['y']
df.loc[:, cols].head()
```

Or add mask with chain by bitwise OR:

```
mask = df.columns.str.contains('x.*?') | (df.columns == 'y')
df.loc[:, mask].head()
```

Or use [`str.startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) with tuple:

```
mask = df.columns.str.startswith(('x','y'))
df.loc[:, mask].head()
```

If there are only `x` with numbers or one letter columns names use [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html):

```
df.filter(regex='x|y').head()
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'x':list('abcdef'),
        'x2':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
        'y':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
        'z':[1,3,5,7,1,0],

})

print (df)
   x  x2  y  z
0  a   4  7  1
1  b   5  8  3
2  c   4  9  5
3  d   5  4  7
4  e   5  2  1
5  f   4  3  0

mask = df.columns.str.startswith(('x','y'))
print(df.loc[:, mask].head())
   x  x2  y
0  a   4  7
1  b   5  8
2  c   4  9
3  d   5  4
4  e   5  2
```